# Angular: Disable a Button dependent on a If condition

Tags: angular, typescript

At the moment I have if condition where if the API call sees 0 then the button to go to the next page should be disabled, however I am not sure how to do this as you cannot call a method within another method(?) right now I have the following

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class=" primary-button mat-raised-button buttontxt" (click)="next()">Next</button>
```

TS:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.showLoader(true);
    this.coachService.GetCategories().subscribe(res =>
     {
      if (res && res.length === 0){
          this.appService.openSnackBar('You do not have access to this Service');
         //This line is where I thought to call this method to disable the button
          this.next = [disabled];
          } else if (res && res.length === 1) {
            if( res[0].name === 'pageOne'){
               //irrelevent code          }
//Button

nextMindset(){
//route to pageOne
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a control variable, for example, `disabled`.

```js
disabled: boolean = true;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.appService.showLoader(true);
  this.coachService.GetCategories().subscribe(res => {
    if (res && res.length === 0){
      this.appService.openSnackBar('You do not have access to this Service');
      this.next = [disabled];
      this.disabled = true;
    } else if (res && res.length === 1) {
      this.disabled = false;
      if( res[0].name === 'pageOne'){
        //irrelevent code          
      }
    }
  }
}

next(){
  if (disabled) return;
  //route to pageOne
}
```

template

```html
<button type="button"
  class=" primary-button mat-raised-button buttontxt"
  (click)="next()"
  [disabled]="disabled">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <button type="button"
            class=" primary-button mat-raised-button buttontxt"
            (click)="next()"
            [disabled]="resLength"
    >Next</button>
```

TS:

```
    resLength = false;

    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.showLoader(true);
    this.coachService.GetCategories().subscribe(res =>
     {

      resLength = !!res.length;

      if (res && res.length === 0){
          this.appService.openSnackBar('You do not have access to this Service');
         //This line is where I thought to call this method to disable the button
          this.next = [disabled];
       } else if (res && res.length === 1) {
            if( res[0].name === 'pageOne'){
               //irrelevent code          }
    
    //Button
    
    nextMindset(){
    //route to pageOne
      }
```

Comment: This is giving me a error of 'Type 'number' is not assignable to type '() => void'' on the TS file

Comment: Sory, In the click event, the name of the variable res.length for the next method is the same. you should change the name of one of them

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean